# How to verify the syntax of an AWS CLI Command without actually performing any action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to verify the syntax of an AWS CLI Command without actually performing any action e.g. verify if the below CLI command to create ec2 instance is correct, including the parameters specified, without actually provisioning the ec2 instance?

The reason I am looking for this is because, I have to test multiple AWS Commands with different options and don't want to provision or impact any resources as a part of testing my commands.

I know there is a [validate template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-validate-template.html) option for CloudFormation but trying to find it's equivalent for AWS CLI. The reason I gave the example of CloudFormation validate template option is not to equate the two, but more as an analogy.

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-0abcdef1234567890 \
    --instance-type t2.micro \
    --subnet-id subnet-08fc749671b2d077c \
    --security-group-ids sg-0b0384b66d7d692f9 \
    --associate-public-ip-address \
    --key-name MyKeyPair
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Getting help with the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-help.html):

> `--dry-run | --no-dry-run` (boolean)
> Checks whether you have the required  permissions  for  the  action,
> without actually making the request, and provides an error response.
> If you have the required permissions, the error response is  `DryRun-Operation`. Otherwise, it is `UnauthorizedOperation`.

Comment: Thank you John. However, when I use the --dry-run option ```aws emr create-cluster \
 --dry-run \ --name "EMRClusterName" ``` I get the error Unknown options: --dry-run. This happens, irrespective if whether I put the --dry-run option at the beginning or at the end. Any inputs why this may be happening?

Comment: Ah! It must only be available for _some_ commands. I see it is mentioned in [run-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) but it is _not_ listed for [create-cluster — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.29/reference/emr/create-cluster.html). In that case, no, there is no way to test that command.